# How to remove a from a list with specific size

Tags: python

I'm Doing this simple list to remove the elemen from the list depend on the the number that. i gave to it

```
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

ls =2
for i in range(0,ls):
    print(mylist[i])

print(mylist)
```

i wanna remove the other from the array and keen the rest depend on the ls if it 1 it will keep the first if it 2 it will keep the first two and so on

Comment: Have you tried [list slicing](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-list-slicing/). Also take a look at a (boardly) [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Comment: I want to know what you are trying to do .do you want to remove all the other element except the one whose inex you are passing??

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing.
For example:

```
>>> mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
>>> print(mylist[:2])
['apple','banana']
```

You can also create a new list with this method

```
>>> mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
>>> my_second_list = mylist[:2]
>>> print(my_second_list)
['apple','banana']
```

Comment: i wanna keep them in the array mean update the array

Comment: using slice operator does not change your original array, "mylist" will keep apple, banana and cherry inside

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the slicing operator for this.

```
print(mylist[:ls])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
ls = 2    # change this to what you want

mylist_cropped = mylist[:ls]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I really understand your question, but if you want to keep first `n` value in list you can try slicing

```
my_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

n = 1
my_list = my_list[:n]  # ["apple"]
```